# WebForms, AJAX and prompt popups elegantly

Tags: asp.net, javascript, asp.net-ajax, webforms

I have a web site already developed with tons of updatePanels, buttons, and integrated functionality.
I have to add some confirmation prompts, these prompts should be customized, and have options like 'Continue', 'Cancel' .
This is a possible scenario:

- The user writes something in one textbox, and then clicks a submit button.
- The Prompt appears.
- When the user clicks continue the page should continue with the normal flow, and when press cancel the  submit action should be stopped.

I want to be the less obtrusive possible,  What is the best approach to achieve this?

**EDIT:**

I can't use any library like Jquery. I can use ModalPopupExtenders, or simply styled divs.
Fundamentally the problem is when clicking this submit button, the submit action is taken and my popup does not appear, even if I add the JS function at onclick Event.
I can ClearAll submit button handlers, add the one that shows my popup, but how can I continue with the 'submit' action when the popup's 'continue' btn is clicked?

Comment: This is way too open-ended a question to answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: Answering your ***updated*** question:

- Hook the form's `submit` event, trigger your pop-up, and return false (if using a DOM0 or jQuery handler) or call `preventDefault` if using a modern handler.
- When you're ready to really submit the form, call the form's `submit` function. This doesn't trigger the `submit` event on conformant browser (but test with all your target browsers, obviously)

Original answer:

Zoidberg has pointed to a specific implementation (and a good one, from what I've heard).  There are several others.

The general principle works like this:

- Create an absolutely-positioned  `iframe` that covers all of the content on the page; you can use opacity on the `iframe` to "grey-out" everything it covers if you like. The `iframe` doesn't have to have any content, it's just there as a backdrop. This is usually called the "`iframe` shim" trick. Give the `iframe` a z-index higher than that of any other element on the page.
- Create an absolutely-positioned `div` on top of the `iframe` (higher in the z-order) containing your dialog box and the options the user has. Note that this is not within the `iframe`'s document, it's part of your main page's DOM.
- When the user has selected an option, remove your `div` and `iframe` and do whatever else you need to do (go to another page, update things, etc.).

The `iframe` serves at least a couple of purposes:

- It lets you readily grey-out the underlying content
- It eats mouse clicks
- It deals with issues with form fields on Internet Explorer

EDIT: And for the record, the majority of JavaScript UI toolkits provide this sort of "modal" functionality, including jQuery UI, YUI, Dojo, Glow, ...

Answer (score 1):

Why not just add something like this to the button's OnClientClick event?

```
OnClientClick = "javascript: return confirm('Your message here.');"
```

Comment: So I have to modify the OnCLientCLick on every button on the page? if I show my custom popup, the same for every button, how can I determine if my popup 'Custom prompt' returns true or false to continue or stop the flow of the app?

Comment: My original idea is setting the "continue" btn handler dinamically when clicking the button that makes the popup appears.

Comment: Since I don't know what your form looks like it's hard to say. Do you have multiple forms? How many buttons submit? T.J.'s updated answer re: form submit is a nice one.

Answer (score 0):

YUI has some nice dialogs.

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/container/simpledialog-quickstart.html

They can even be made to be modal just like this loading panel

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/container/panel-loading.html

Answer (score 0):

You can't go wrong w/ jQuery UI.  They have a modal dialog widget.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-confirmation